# Prevent the check of a mat-checkbox by clicking on its label

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular12

I need to prevent the check of a checkbox by clicking on its label.

I use the angular material checkbox.

I partially manage to do it using the `preventDefault()` method but the checkbox still shows focus style if I click on the label.

What I need is: if I click on the label, nothing should happen to the checkbox (not checked, not focused on).

Please take a look at this stackblitz link to better understand my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zyvdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` as CSS on your element

Comment: It doesn't work. now the label can check the checkbox, again :) you can try on the stackblitz example (link provided above)

Comment: Just move the label outside of the mat-checkbox tag it will work fine.

Comment: good idea! thank you @akpgp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change ripple behavior or CSS, try this:

```html
<span (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" (click)="check($event)">
    Check me!
</span>
```

The ripple effect is triggered from the mousedown event (hence why you don't see them when using the space bar), and you need to use `stopPropagation()`, as `preventDefault()` isn't enough here.

StackBlitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zyvdp-vzshvz?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add below css in style.css & check

```
span.mat-ripple.mat-checkbox-ripple.mat-focus-indicator {background: none !important;opacity: 0 !important;}
```